# Single Sign On (SSO) - workflow

Tags: php, angularjs, oauth, single-sign-on

I am looking to implement SSO in all my future php/angular applications. I see there are services (Auth0, oauth.io, etc) that are sort of the middle man of an SSO app and there are protocols such as OAuth 1.0/2.0 but in regards to creating a custom SSO solution (using aforementioned OAuth protocols, I assume), I am a little foggy on the complete flow of the process.

**What I do get:**

- App gets Access Token
- (optional) App validates Access Token
- App (with Access Token) gets access to a particular API and returns result. For
  example, Facebook profile information.

**What I don't get:**

What to do with that information once I have it. Do I retain the access token and request information from the API source each time they login? How do I relate my own application data to the API data? Would I create a different kind of user record that just contains the access token and application's userid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do I retain the access token and request information from the API source each time they login?**

If the token does not expire, you can hold on to it in a data store and use it with each request.  Many times, though, the token will expire, and you need to request a new one each time you start a session.  In this case you'd probably store the token in memory instead of a permanent storage location.

**How do I relate my own application data to the API data?**

I think we'd need to know a little more about your application to answer this question.

**Would I create a different kind of user record that just contains the access token and application's userid?**

Again, we'd probably need a little more information about your application.  If you were persisting the token (in the case that it doesn't expire), then you need to make some considerations about how you want to store it.  If not, you can probably just put it into a local variable or session.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! In regards to application specifics, I am referring to any generic method of relating application user data such as comments or comic book collections or answers to a question or any sort of data that would live within an application that is related to a application's user.

Comment: Common generic places to store OAuth information would be a database, config file, cache or session.  Maybe put your secret key in a config file, and your session key in cache or some sort of temporary storage like memcache.

Comment: I guess the main area of confusion is would the information gained from OAuth (or whatever SSO implementation) update my application's user table? So 1.) Get OAuth data 2.) Check for existing application user record based on email (?) 3a.) If does not exist, populate fname, profile pic, lname (for example) into my database 3b) Otherwise, update application user data. I could be way off.

Comment: That is a perfectly acceptable workflow.  The only gotcha is if the token expires, then you might also have to check the validity of the token you have in your user table.